# InstantObjects looks good, but I can't find any code to use MySQL with it.

Tags: mysql, delphi, instantobjects

I am trying to develop an application in the OO way. That is, I intend to design objects for all business components rather than design a form for a process. I am completely new to this.

Anyhow, I discovered InstantObjects and was quite impressed. However, I don't see any code that can help me use MySQL with it.

Has anyone done this before?

Nirav

Comment: Are you tried asking this question in the `InstantObjects Newsgroups` http://www.instantobjects.org/#newsgroups ?

Comment: Here's a link to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954934/how-can-i-create-objects-with-reference-using-instantobjects-framework-programmat

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, u can use mySQL ODBC driver, ADO COnnection, InsntanObject ADO Broker to connect mySQL. Don't use DBExpresse since it doenst support mySQL 5.